# Having the same method with two different behaviors?

Tags: java, design-patterns

My question is not Java specific but I think it's more like a design-patterns question.
I'll try to explain with an example :

I have two classes (A and B), B is extending A.
The two classes look like this :

```
public class A {

    protected int method1() {
        System.out.println(method3());
    }

    protected int method3() {
        return 3;
    }

}
```

.

```
public class B extends A {

    protected void method2() {
        //Calling method1
        method1(); // Output : 3

        //Calling method1 another time but method3 needs to be slightly different
        method1(); // Output needs to be : 6
    }
}
```

So, I'd like to call two times the same method but I want to modify what is inside method3() when calling it the second time.
Obviously I don't want to define two different method1() because method1 is not only printing out an int but it is doing more.

The second method3 could look like this :

```
protected int method3bis() {
    return 2*3;
}
```

I'd really like to avoid passing some kind of argument through all the methods, something which would look like this :

```
protected int method1(int arg) {
    if(arg == 0)
        System.out.println(method3());

    if(arg == 1)
        System.out.println(method3bis());
}
```

Do you know any good way to do this ?
Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Sounds like you want to override `method1` in class B.

Comment: You can possibly add a counter in method1 that will increment when used and then use that counter for the second time it is called.

Comment: @Zéychin agreed. You will still need to write the new behavior in the override.

Comment: Define a member in the base class and change its value everytime you call method1. You still need to write an if else statement but you can at least avoid passing arguments.

Comment: How is your program supposed to know which of the two behaviours you want?

Comment: @brifbraff, I tried doing this but it's a multi-threading environment and I'm not sure about adding some synchronized as it will slow down the program.

Comment: @DavidWallace , that's the question. I'd like to redefine method3 before calling method1

Comment: Yes, but how is the computer supposed to KNOW which version you want?  Under what circumstances should it call one version of the method; and under what circumstances should it call the other?  It can't read your mind - you need to express your requirements WAY more clearly!

Comment: @CodeWhisperer Well, I guess that depends. If we just call `B.super.method1` and then call `b.method1`, then we're fine and we get the desired output, if I understand correctly. It's hard to tell how this is going to be used as the question is currently defined.

Comment: What you are trying to accomplish is an anti-pattern. It goes against the Single Responsibility Design Principle: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to change the implementation of a method at run time in Java.

When you override a method, it is possible to call the direct superclass implementation, for example:

```
class Super {
    void method1() {
        System.out.println(3);
    }
}

class Sub {
    @Override
    void method1() {
        System.out.println(2 * 3);
    }

    void method2() {
        // printing 3
        super.method1();

        // printing 6
        this.method1();
    }
}
```

However, this cannot be used in the way you have described (calling *method1* while changing the implementation of *method3*). And it would also be a very disorganized way to implement what you have described.

You should use method parameters because this is what they are for.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with reflection by creating a new A object, but this is not a good way to go about it. You're better off using if/else blocks.

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;

public class B extends A {

        protected void method2() {

            try {
                Class a = Class.forName("A");
                Object aa = a.newInstance();
                ((A) aa).method1(); // Output : 3
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }



            //Calling method1 another time but method3 needs to be slightly different
            this.method1(); // Output needs to be : 6
        }

        @Override
        protected int method3() {
            return 2*3;
        }

}
```

Comment: In both cases method3 from subclass will be called